# Ftp uploading issues on phpStorm 7.1

Tags: ftp, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

**Edit:** It seems that after the last update this issue is no longer present, at least so far

---

Whenever i try to upload a file i get a combination of the following errors and success at upload time.

```
[5/20/14 7:20 PM] Upload to ***
[5/20/14 7:20 PM] Failed to transfer file 'C:\wamp\www\***\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-api.php': could not create FTP directory "ftp://ftp.***.com/woocommerce".


[5/20/14 7:21 PM] Upload to ***
[5/20/14 7:21 PM] Upload to *** completed in less than a minute: 1 file transferred (3.7 Kb/s)


[5/20/14 7:21 PM] Upload to ***
[5/20/14 7:22 PM] Failed to transfer file 'C:\wamp\www\***\wp-content\plugins\paymentez-wooc-gateway\index.php': could not close the output stream for file "ftp://ftp.***.com/paymentez-wooc-gateway/index.php".
```

[image: Console ss, showing ide errors on ftp upload]

I've disabled my firewall, and no luck, i've tried passive mode in the ftp and same problem, i can upload the same files and folders using filezilla on the same ftp account so i assume the problem is in phpstorm, not sure if it is a bug or a missconfiguration on my part. I have this issue on other websites hosted in different servers, and i'm not quite sure but i don't recall having this issue under windows 7, now i'm under windows 8.

Sometimes it uploads ok, and most of the time it fails.

Any thoughts are highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Me too -same problem. Was working fine now suddenly no files will upload. Works fine with Cyberduck etc. If not resolved soon I'm going back to Dreamweaver!

Comment: Also same problem using PhpStorm v8.0.1 - Windows 7.. any suggestions someone ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I notice I have this issue in my phpstorm if I have another ftp client connected to same server so what I actually did is to close my ftp client filezilla and then start working correctly .....

Another option is to set FTP on "passive mode" from Deployment=>Selected server=>Advanced Options.

Comment: I've tested setting the FTP to passive mode before and it didn't work, but now that you mention it, it might be possible that i had filezilla open at the same time, i haven't had that problem in a while, but I'll try to check for that when it happens, and if it does i'll accept your answer, thanks.

Comment: Setting connection in passive mode solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

In my case server's partition was full. Try to check size of partition by typing in bash:

`df`

Then make some space, by removing files with `rm` or moving `mv` files to another partition.

Apart of that I could successfully transfer my files through the FileZilla but not with PHPStorm automatic deployment upload (weird).

Answer (score 3):

So after hours of trying i have a solution.
I am using sftp which is different than ftp a bit.
However for me it was that my server's storage was almost full and denied packets to be sent there. I increased the size of the hard drive and allocated the amount of the increased size.

Comment: That is just another way to say that you don't know why it happens.

Comment: My disk on the remote server was full and hence causing this issue

Answer (score 2):

in deployment/connection change type to "ftps".

Answer (score 1):

I had accidentally pasted in the `Deployment path on server` with ***a space in the path***. Removing that remedied things.

Answer (score -5):

My solution was to simply change to a faster Internet connection.